# interpreting perf tool results on different NUMA nodes

Tags: cpu, scheduler, numa, perf

I want to explain, using perf tool, an interesting behavior of my program.

**Some background info**

My machine has 4 NUMA nodes and my main application is running on the machine. Using cpusets I'm partitioning the machine to give 3 nodes to the application and 1 to the system. While running a unittest(for logging improvements) on the same machine I get unexpected behavior which I'm trying to investigate using the perf tool.

**The unexpected behavior** is that on the NUMA node where the application is running(lets say node2) some I get better times on my unittest, around twice as low as the ones when the unittest is running on the NUMA node with the system(let's say node3). It looks like running on a CPU of a node2(a cpu which does not do spinlock) I get better results than running on another numa.

I'm trying to improve my logging system, so the test is doing work which is also done by the application, writing some log messages to a queue for later dump to the disk(different thread). Contention to the queue is controlled by a spinlock(CAS). The unitest is one writer thread which has 2 loops: 100 times, 1000 logs are written to the queue and RDTSC(my choice) is used to measure each internal loop and then statistics is printed. Queue is big enough, I get a got standard deviation, memory operations are reduced to a minimum(no memcpy). The reader is dumping to the disk on another thread.

I tried stopping my application and running the test again. I see in this case that regardless of the NUMA node selected to run my test I get results similar with running on the node3(slow), meaning that the application being run is speeding up my test, if I run my test on the same numa node the application runs. Very unintuitive for me.

**Using the following perf tool command to grab some data**

```
rm /tmp/a; rm /tmp/ats; for f in $(perf list | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f 2 ); do perf stat -o /tmp/ats --append -e $f taskset -c $(cat /sys/devices/system/node/node2/cpulist) ./bin/testCore >> /tmp/a 2>&1;perf stat -o /tmp/ats --append -e $f taskset -c $(cat /sys/devices/system/node/node3/cpulist) ./bin/testCore >> /tmp/a 2>&1;done
```

and using the command to analyze

```
cat /tmp/ats | grep -v "#" | grep -v "^ *$" | grep -v "seconds time elapsed\|Performance\|supported" | grep -v " 0 " | tr -s ' ' | tr -d ',' | awk '{if(knownEvent[$2]){if(((knownEvent[$2]/$1)<0.95) || ((knownEvent[$2]/$1)>1.05)){printf "diff:%s %.2f(%d/%d)\n",$2,(knownEvent[$2]/$1),knownEvent[$2],$1}}else{knownEvent[$2]=$1}}'| more
diff:branch-misses 1.08(470184/435284)
diff:bus-cycles 0.70(25570333/36774093)
diff:cpu-clock 0.69(191/276)
diff:L1-dcache-prefetch-misses 1.05(624172/593780)
diff:LLC-loads 0.92(665199/720197)
diff:LLC-load-misses 1.16(217684/187823)
diff:LLC-prefetches 0.87(193398/222148)
diff:LLC-prefetch-misses 0.85(98653/115483)
diff:dTLB-load-misses 1.09(195668/180291)
diff:dTLB-store-misses 1.11(39755/35910)
diff:scsi:scsi_dispatch_cmd_start 1.38(11/8)
diff:block:block_rq_insert 0.58(36/62)
diff:block:block_rq_issue 1.50(12/8)
diff:block:block_bio_backmerge 1.05(683/650)
diff:block:block_getrq 0.57(36/63)
diff:block:block_plug 0.52(26/50)
diff:kmem:mm_pagevec_free 1.06(16853/15838)
diff:kmem:mm_kernel_pagefault 0.88(7/8)
diff:timer:timer_start 0.36(21/59)
diff:timer:timer_expire_entry 3.00(3/1)
diff:timer:timer_expire_exit 2.00(2/1)
diff:timer:timer_cancel 1.60(8/5)
diff:timer:hrtimer_start 0.93(1275/1368)
diff:timer:hrtimer_expire_entry 0.72(186/259)
diff:timer:hrtimer_expire_exit 0.69(182/264)
diff:timer:hrtimer_cancel 0.74(192/259)
diff:irq:softirq_entry 0.64(374/585)
diff:irq:softirq_exit 0.74(394/536)
diff:irq:softirq_raise 0.73(390/531)
diff:sched:sched_wakeup 0.75(3/4)
diff:sched:sched_stat_wait 0.50(1/2)
diff:sched:sched_stat_sleep 2.00(2/1)
diff:sched:sched_stat_runtime 0.93(1284/1379)
```

I extracted the ones I see containing some difference. 
**Not sure if I should suspect the sched-, LLC-,  branch-, TLB because I have no clue if the relative difference expalains the behavior I see.**

Any suggestion of a better way to investigate this?

Comment: Some more information: it seems that adding a cpu burner is determining my program to behave better. Having on each NUMA node a simple C program with while(1) inside and starting it on a core(using taskset) makes somehow the test to run twice as fast. **Does anyone have any ideea if is the scheduler?** I tried to replace the rdtsc with this method [http://download.intel.com/embedded/software/IA/324264.pdf](http://download.intel.com/embedded/software/IA/324264.pdf) to make sure my measurements are correct(no out of order execution takes place), and they are ok.

Comment: Problem fixed: it had to do with the performance setting of the CPUs. Cpu sleep states were creating this behavior and it seems that putting a cpu burner on the NUMA node makes the CPUs not falling into sleep, hence I did not paid the latency penalty of waking up.